# Dependency injection and state setup

Tags: dependency-injection

I'd like to ask who is responsible for setting up the injected dependency's state?

For e.g when class A depends on class B, is instance A's responsibility to setup instance B or should it be done somewhere else? Why?

My questions is much more a general one, but I put the concrete situation here:
I have a Context class which handles interactions and states made to a given chart, e.g. you can switch between two series. However this class is also setting up chart's look and displayed data with by delegating them to other (injected) classes. Currently the Context constructor sets up its dependencies state based on its constructor parameters (e.g.: highlight one point on the chart, telling which series to display, etc). I'm not sure that this design is good and would like to get a deeper understanding about the right way. The programming language is Javascript (if it's matters).

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

> when class A depends on class B, is instance A's responsibility to setup instance B or should it be done somewhere else?

If A would be responsibly of setting up B, this would make A violate the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) (DIP) that says:

> High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should
>   depend on abstractions.

The DIP is the driving force behind the Dependency Injection pattern.

But if A can't be responsible of creating B, who is? The answer to this question is: The [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/):

> A Composition Root is a (preferably) unique location in an application
>   where modules are composed together.

Using a Composition Root is the only way that you can keep both A and B (and everything else in the graph) free from having a dependency on a different module.